# How to include specific node_modules to load into webpack?

Tags: react-native, webpack, babeljs

I'm using `react-native-web` and I've come across a couple of projects that do not compile their babel code ([react-native-popover](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-popover) and [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)). So I need to compile these `node_modules`. I know the `babel-preset-react-native` preset exists. Is there any way I can use the babel loader I currently have (see below) and also include another loader for the above mentioned packages? Ideally any `node_module` that is prefaced with `react-native` would be loaded using `babel-preset-react-native`.

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: [
      'react-hot',
      'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true'
    ]
  },
```

Comment: `exclude: /node_modules/` here is your answer

Comment: What? That is gonna include all modules, which I don't want.

Comment: You're right, I should have been more precise: hint to get your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclude takes a regular expression. You can use something like this to get your desired effect.

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!react-native)/
```